# In VS Code, how can I disable justMyCode when running pytest in "Testing" tab

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, pytest

When debugging unit tests through the GUI, I don't know how to configure VS Code to step inside third-party code.
Note: I use a workspace.

[image]

---

Edit: Currently **as a workaround** I can use this configuration from "Run and Debug tab" where I have to specify which test I want to run:

```json
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Debug specific test",
        "type": "python",
        "module": "pytest",
        "request": "launch",
        "purpose": ["debug-test"],
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "justMyCode": false,
        "args": [
            "explorer/test/test_projects_controller.py::TestProjectsController::test_get_metadata"
        ]
    }
]``
```

Comment: are you clicking the run button (play icon) or the run and debug button (play icon with bug)?

Comment: The debug button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation in current VSCode version: VSCode only uses `launch.json` file to configure pytest debugging options, it ignores the workspace launch section.
It is planned to be fixed soon: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/21249
As a workaround, we can duplicate the workspace launch section in a `.vscode/launch.json` file, ex:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Debug Tests",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "purpose": ["debug-test"],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false,
            "presentation": {
                "hidden": true, // keep original launch order in 'run and debug' tab
            }
        },
    ],
    "version": "0.2.0"
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I'd try following the instructions from [the VS Code Python docs' section on debugging tests](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_debug-tests), which states:

> To customize settings for debugging tests, you can specify `"purpose": ["debug-test"]` in the `launch.json` file in the `.vscode` folder from your workspace. This configuration will be used when you run Test: Debug All Tests, Test: Debug Tests in Current File and Test: Debug Test at Cursor commands.
>
> For example, the configuration below in the `launch.json` file disables the `justMyCode` setting for debugging tests:
>
> ```json
> {
>   "name": "Python: Debug Tests",
>   "type": "python",
>   "request": "launch",
>   "program": "${file}",
>   "purpose": ["debug-test"],
>   "console": "integratedTerminal",
>   "justMyCode": false
> }
> ```
>
> If you have more than one configuration entry with `"purpose": ["debug-test"]`, the first definition will be used since we currently don't support multiple definitions for this request type.

Note: I've also seen older configs floating around that use `"request": "test"` instead of `"purpose": ["debug-test"]` (Ex. [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/7131#issuecomment-525873210)), so you can try that if `"purpose": ["debug-test"]` doesn't work for you.

There also seems to be a `"debugStdLib": true` property you can use if you want to step into standard library things ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/10637#issuecomment-601082975)).

There's an open issue ticket where this is apparently not working for version 2023.8.0 of the Python extension ([#21249](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/21249)), but it will be fixed in later versions. Also potentially related: [Pytest restart debugger works only with code-workspace files
#21365](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/21365).

Comment: Thanks for the link to the documentation.  
However it doesn't work as expected

Comment: It works for me, as long as the breakpoint is in the app's own codebase.